# GNU R - How do I stitch together two data.frames with different size

Tags: r, list, dataframe

My dataframe "Baeume" is a big list of trees.
Every tree has a number and some corresponding houses.
Since a tree can have several corresponding houses there can be several rows with one treenumber and different houses.
With the following code i counted, how many times a treenumber appeared in the list - which gives me the number of corresponding houses per tree.

```
Baeume <- read.table(file="C:\\SecondFinal.txt",header = TRUE, sep=";", dec = ".")

attach(Baeume)

a <- rle(Baeume[["IN_FID"]])

b <- data.frame(number=a$values, n=a$lengths)
```

So now i have the Information I wanted - how many houses correspond to each treenumber.

Now i want to create a new column on the original "Baeume" dataframe where in every row the number of corresponding houses per treenumber appear.

But since my dataframe "Baeume" and "b" have different lenghts i can not use the "append"-command.

How can i tell R to write in each row after every treenumber the value already counted in  "b"?

For Example:
Treenumber 605 appears in 15 rows, so R should write "15" in a newly created column in each row of tree 605 and so on...

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: we would some sample data to actually work on and also share the expected output. else we can't keep guessing the solution. thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot guys -  problem solved! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use function merge(), it that's what you want.

Comment: merge() worked - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

having sample data would make this easier to answer. but you could do the following:

library(dplyr)

```
trees_summary <- trees %>%
    group_by(treenumber) %>%
    summarise(Count = n())

trees2 <- trees %>%
    left_join(trees_summary, by = "treenumber")
```

The first new df is a summary of the count of your data by the treenumber, like

```
treenumber   Count
tree 605     15
tree 478     7
```

etc.

then the second piece which creates the tree2 df, will do a left_join (or merge),

```
Treenumber    Count
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 605      15
tree 478      7
tree 478      7
tree 478      7
tree 478      7
tree 478      7
tree 478      7
tree 478      7
```

Comment: thank you - thant helped me understand how this stuff works! :D